# Unable to set center of map in bootstrap vertical tabs

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I have used GEM Named: [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) which is doing perfect job somehow but the problem is that I am unable to center my map. Its showing in very corner.

What I want to do is, show the map having MASSACHUSETTS as center having number of pins in it.

I am also using Tabs in which they are loading now but unable to figured it out how I can adjust to set it center with MASSACHUSETTS.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEYGOESHERE" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng('42.0574342', '-72.8422761');
    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({
          provider: {
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoom: 12,
            center: map_center
          },
          internal: {
            id: 'map'
          }
        },
        function () {
          var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @retailers.to_json %>);
          handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
          handler.fitMapToBounds();
        }
    );
    $('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize', {});
      var reCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('42.0574342', '-72.8422761');
      handler.setCenter(reCenter);
    });
  });
</script>
```

And Div:

```
<div style='width: 825px; height: 350px;'>
<div id="map" style='width: 825px; height: 350px;'></div>
</div>
```

Here is sample pic:

[image]

Here is the demo:

```js
  var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(42.0574342, -72.8422761);
  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({
      provider: {
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoom: 12,
        center: map_center
      },
      internal: {
        id: 'map'
      }
    },
    function() {
      var markers = handler.addMarkers([{
        "lat": "42.3420564",
        "lng": "-71.1377384",
        "marker_title": "BRIX Wine Shop"
      }, {
        "lat": "42.3484068",
        "lng": "-71.1563419",
        "marker_title": "Bauer Wine \u0026 Spirits"
      }, {
        "lat": "42.3560102",
        "lng": "-71.1275915",
        "marker_title": "Boston Wine Exchange"
      }, {
        "lat": "42.3484068",
        "lng": "-71.1563419",
        "marker_title": "Bauer Wine \u0026 Spirits"
      }]);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    }
  );
  $('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize', {});
    var reCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(42.0574342, -72.8422761);
    handler.setCenter(reCenter);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVGMRkZg8rFSxoUspEiZmnaMRqT3WO8wU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js"></script>



<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>




<div style='width: 825px; height: 350px;'>
                        <div id="map" style='width: 825px; height: 350px;'></div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: may not be the ideal solution but try wrapping `setCenter()` in `setTimout()`

Comment: Could you post some code how I should? I believe this is not the case but may be its.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ handler.setCenter(reCenter)},50 );`

Comment: @charlietfl still same result :-)

Comment: those should be numbers not strings for lat/long

Comment: Still no difference. thanks.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use `Gmaps` if you use the map `API`.
Try with just this:

**EDITED** to add a loop that creates markers from an array (and slight changes).

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 9,
        center: {lat:42.25, lng: -71.80},   // Center of Massachusetts
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var coord_List = [
        {lat: 42.0574342, lng: -72.8422761},    // Your coords // A

        // Other coords just for the example.
        {lat:42.40115038362434, lng: -72.18292236328125},   // B    
        {lat:42.52474804234817, lng: -73.0535888671875},    // C    
        {lat:42.55914981211588, lng: -71.2957763671875},    // D
        {lat:42.116561350389006, lng: -71.4495849609375},   // E
        {lat:41.95949009892467, lng: -70.02410888671875}    // F
    ];

    // Marker letters
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var labelIndex = 0;

    for(i=0;i<coord_List.length;i++){
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coord_List[i],
            label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
            map: map
        });
    }
}
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVGMRkZg8rFSxoUspEiZmnaMRqT3WO8wU&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**Notice** that I use your API key followed by a callback.
This callback must be the name of your map creation function.

**From my first answer, I changed:**
The `zoom` from 14 to 9, Which is better to view all Massachusetts.
You may prefer 8... (Lower number is higher altitude)
The map type to `ROADMAP` which I think is best for bar locations.
Map type options are: `ROADMAP`, `TERRAIN`, `SATELLITE` and `HYBRYD`
And I slightly changed the «center of Massachusetts» coord because the islands where off my screen.

You mentionned, in comments, that you have the coords in database...
So make your PHP produce this `coord_List` array.
;)

Also... This is needed in `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300">

<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
</style>
```

-------------
**BUG FIX**

Since your produced coords are like this:

```
[
    {"lat":"42.0574342","lng":"-72.8422761"},    // Your coords // A

    // Other coords just for the example.
    {"lat":"42.40115038362434","lng":"-72.18292236328125"}, // B    
    {"lat":"42.52474804234817","lng":"-73.0535888671875"},  // C    
    {"lat":"42.55914981211588","lng":"-71.2957763671875"},  // D
    {"lat":"42.116561350389006","lng":"-71.4495849609375"}, // E
    {"lat":"41.95949009892467","lng":"-70.02410888671875"}  // F
]
```

You have to remove those `"`.
Add this loop before the one that sets markers:

```
for(i=0;i<coord_List.length;i++){
    coord_List[i].toString().replace(/\"/g, "");
    coord_List[i].lat = parseFloat(coord_List[i].lat);
    coord_List[i].lng = parseFloat(coord_List[i].lng);
    console.log(coord_List[i]);
}
```

The rest remains unchanged.

Comment: I am using GEM like I said so therefore per documentation I was using that. Your code seems working somehow but how I can populate multiple markers on it within that position as I need to show all pins within Massachusetts. Any workaround?

Comment: You can place as many marker as you want... I'm not sure to understand the question.

Comment: Am I right to understand that you have a big list of coords and that you want to show ONLY the ones in Massachusetts ?

Comment: I am sorry, let me explain you. I want to show number of bars with in just MA. So what my understanding is to show list of bars having lat lon and pin them on MA by sitting MA as center. Got it?

Comment: I do have have big list of coords, but they belongs to just MA only so I am trying to sitting MA as center so all pins will be easily shown on map making MA as center. Suppose if I have 20 bars in my db that all are in MA, so I will set MA as my center so my ping wouldn't goes away anywhere but kept showing on MA only. all bars are from MA only. My main aim is show all pings on map so no ping will be missed or go aside from the bounds of maps. I really do not like clusters or other things. I need to show all my pins with in MA as a center.

Comment: My concept of center could be wrong as well but my goal is to show all my pins on MA as they all belongs to MA only. And no ping should be go out of the bounds. Anyone open the map and all pins on MA will be shown to him as pins are from MA only.

Comment: ok. While I'm trying it on my side... Just notice that the "map center" is specified here : `center: {lat:42.35, lng: -72.15},   // Center of Massachusetts` But is is only a initial centering. User can move the map after it is loaded. The `zoom: 14` is the initial altitude. Maybe you could ajust it closer with a higher number.

Comment: Fine, that make more sense. So, how I could populate list of markers then? Also can we manage if in future the list of pins start to get bigger so map will handle them automatically with in map bounds? Any idea?
Also would you mind posting complete working code as well. Thanks.!

Comment: Is that really necessary to give `{lat:42.40115038362434, lng: -72.18292236328125}`, because using ruby I have `{"lat":"42.3420564","lng":"-71.1377384"}` and so its not parsing my data. I tried to use `JSON.parse(coord_List)` but its also not working. My actual response is: `var coord_List = [{"lat":"42.3420564","lng":"-71.1377384"},{"lat":"42.3560102","lng":"-71.1275915"},{"lat":"42.3484068","lng":"-71.1563419"},{"lat":"42.3845026","lng":"-71.1891644"},{"lat":"42.4258581","lng":"-71.2651176"}];`

Comment: It says: `Uncaught TypeError: coord_List[i].replace is not a function`

Comment: Maybe because it's not considered a string... Hold on, I will try something on my side.

Comment: Yes the keys should be represented as object notations like `key:` while value can be in double quotes. with your sample data its really working fine.

Comment: Values must not have quote... I tried and the API replies *«setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number»*. I found your fix. See edit. ;)

Comment: Haha, yes, you were right. :-) You are indeed a best programmer. I never saw such a wonderful person from Quebec before ;) 
Thanks so much Sir. You are my hero.